# problemas en formulario con input text y input file

Tags: nodejs, formularios

Estoy haciendo un proyecto que requiere un formulario con varios campos input text y con un input file, y me sucede algo muy curioso y es que apenas le doy el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` al formulario, los datos de los input text no son enviados en el cuerpo de la solicitud. tengo problemas con este tema

Estoy usando `express-formidable` y `formidable` para subir el archivo, los archivos los procesa bien, pero me hacen falta los datos de los otros campos. resalto que cuando quito la propiedad `enctype="multipart/form-data"` al formularios, los datos de los campos input text se envian correctamente en el cuerpo de la solicitud pero así no puedo subir el archivo del

**archivo app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var formidable = require('express-formidable');



var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
app.use(formidable({
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  uploadDir: __dirname+'/public/images',
  keepExtensions: true,
  multiples: true, // req.files to be arrays of files 
})
)

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**archivo index.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
    h1=title
    form.mi-form(action="/f1" method="post" name="f1" )
        div nombre
        input(type="text" name="titulo")
        input(type="file" name="archivo")
        input(type="submit" value="enviar")
```

**archivo index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();



/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
router.post('/f1', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(" --- esto es el cuerpo de la solicitud --- ");
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);

  res.render('index', { title: req.body.titulo });
});
module.exports = router;
```

con esta configuración no me sube los archivos pero los input text son enviados en el cuerpo de la solicitud como lo ven en la imagen siguiente.

[![Navegador web][1]][1]
[![consola][2]][2]

ahora hagamos alguna modificación pequeña en el formulario, colocando el  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` y veamos que pasa.

**index.jade**
extends layout

```
block content
    h1=title
    form.mi-form(action="/f1" method="post" name="f1" enctype="multipart/form-data" )
        div nombre
        input(type="text" name="titulo")
        input(type="file" name="archivo")
        input(type="submit" value="enviar")
```

y este es el resultado que da

[![Navegador web][1]][1]
[image: consola caso 2]

Podemos ver que los datos no fueron enviados en el cuerpo de la solicitud
¿cual sería el problema?

Hagamos otra modificación un poco mas grande:

Utilicemos `express-formidable`

**app.js**

```
 var express = require('express');
 var path = require('path');
 var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
 var logger = require('morgan');
 var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var formidable = require('express-formidable');



var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
app.use(formidable({
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  uploadDir: __dirname+'/public/images',
  keepExtensions: true,
  multiples: true, // req.files to be arrays of files 
})
)

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Este es el resultado:

[![Navegador web][1]][1]
[image: consola caso 3]

Esos son los errores que no entiendo que pueda estar pasando,
quien me pueda explicar le agradezco.
En la documentacion de `express-formidable` ni de `formidable` dicen algo de estos errores

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cj4R.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShoVB.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intente con [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) es para subir archivos en el servidor o en una nube, te doy un ejemplo como lo he hecho subiendo en el servidor.

formulario.html

```
 <form action="/newimagect" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="imgct" class="columinput">
   <h2>Nuevo imagen</h2>
   <input type="text" id="idr" name="idr" required style="display:none;" />
   <label for="gimg"></label>
   <input type="file" id="gimg" name="gimg" required />
   <div id="txA"></div>
   <input type="submit" value="Ingresar" id="nvig" />
 </form>
```

imagenes.js

```
 $(inicio_pagina);

 function inicio_pagina () {
    $("#nvig").on("click", subirimage);
 }

 function subirimage () {
   var idob=$("#idr").val()
   var ctimg=$("#gimg")[0].files[0]
   var namectimg=ctimg.name;
   var extectimg=namectimg.substring(namectimg.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
   if (idob=="") {
    $("#txA").text("Id de contenido no disponible")
    return false
   }
   else{
    if (!es_imagen(extectimg)) {
      $("#txA").text("tipo de imagen no permitido")
      return false
    }
    else{
      var formu=new FormData($("#imgct")[0])
      $.ajax({
        url: '/newimagect',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formu,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend:function () {
            $("#txA").prepend('loading');
        },
        success:relimgcont,
        error:function () {
          console.log('error');
        }
       })
       return false
    }
   }
 }

 function relimgcont (res) {
   console.log(res);
 }
```

app.js

```
var express=require("express")
var bodyparse=require("body-parser")
var path=require("path")
var multer=require("multer")

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000

var app=express()

var rutimage=path.join(__dirname,"..","public/images/contenido/")

var storage=multer.diskStorage({
  destination:function (res,file,cb) {
    cb(null,rutimage)
  },
  filename:function (res,file,cb) {
    cb(null,Date.now()+file.originalname)
  }
})

var upload=multer({storage:storage})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")))

app.use(bodyparse.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyparse.json())

app.post("/newimagect",upload.single("gimg"),function (req,res) {
  var id=req.body.idr
  var image=req.file.filename
})

servidor.listen(port,function () {
  console.log("servidor en "+port)
}
```