# Usando Node, Express y Multer para subir un archivo a MongoDB? Que debo usar, Multer o GRIDfs?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose, heroku

Hola estoy ejecutando un proyecto final en Heroku usando MongoLab y Multer para subir fotos, parece funcionar bien, pero después de unas horas o menos las fotos desaparecen de la página, pero deja el marcador de posición img, aparece el símbolo cuando el navegador no puede encontrar la imagen. De hecho abro la consola y aparece ese mensaje que que no puede encontrar el archivo.

Es esto cuestion de Heroku o Mongolab o es sólo la cuenta gratuita de mongoLab. También no importa si hay una foto cargada o una docena todavía desaparecen después de un rato.

¿Hay un hack, una línea complicada de código o algo que hice mal con Multer o mi base de datos? He hecho una investigación profunda en la web y Stack-Overflow he encontrado algo llamado GRIDfs pero no sé si eso funcionará. ¿Estoy en el camino correcto?

Este es mi codigo en Node:

```
var express        = require("express"),
    body_parser    = require("body-parser"),
    multer         = require("multer"),
    mongoose       = require("mongoose");

    var app = express();

    //connect my local database to MongoLab database   

    var url = process.env.DATABASE || "mongodb://localhost/black_hat";

    mongoose.connect(url);
```

Esta es la configuracion de Multer:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function(req, file, callback){
    callback(null, "./public/uploads");
},
filename: function(req, file, callback){
    callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
}
  });

var upload = multer({storage : storage}).single("image");
```

Este es la ruta donde subo la imagen:

```
app.post("/fotos_videos", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if(err){
            return res.end("Error uploading file");
        }
        // get data from form
        var newName = req.body.name,
            newCover = "/uploads/" + req.file.filename;
        // Packing into an object
        var newCollage = {
            name : newName,
            cover: newCover
        };
        //create new album
        Collage.create(newCollage, function(err, collage) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                // console.log(collage);
                res.redirect("/fotos_videos");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

La forma donde envio la imagen:

```html
<div style="width=30%; margin: 30px auto" >
        
        <form action="/fotos_videos" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Album Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Album Name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Choose Album Cover</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" placeholder="image url" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        
        <a href="/fotos_videos">Back</a>
        
    </div>
```

Mi modelo de mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Schema 
var collageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    cover : String,
    photos: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Photo"
    }] 
});

var Collage = mongoose.model("Collage", collageSchema);

module.exports = Collage;
```

Asi que repito todo esta bien al pricipio despliego la forma donde me pide la imagen que quiero subir luego me redirecciona a la pagina donde esa imagen se despliega y esta bien... por unas horas por que despues la imagen desaparece. Leei y encontre que multer no sube las imagenes a la base de datos que para eso debo de usar GRIDfs no se si esa informacion sea del todo correcto?

Comment: No hay suficientes detalles para ayudarte. Te recomiendo que mires la consola del navegador y ver que errores se producen (js o de networking) y  trates de depurar el problema. Una vez tengas esos datos, edita la pregunta y agregalos. Cuanta mas informacion mas facil es brindarte ayuda. Suerte.

Comment: Ok editare la pregunta en un momento espero se comprenda mejor gracias

Comment: Hola, creo que no es necesario usar gridfs, guiate de [aca](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40096/problemas-en-formulario-con-input-text-y-input-file/40206#40206), asi lo huso para subir imagenes con multer.

Comment: Gracias @AlbertArias intentare con tu guia, solo para aclarar y profundizar mas; ya logre subir imagenes con Multer logro que se desplieguen en la pagina pero lo que no logro es que se queden ahi, es decir que despues de un rato subidas las imagenes, estas se borran de la pagina, ¿no se si tu en tus proyectos tengas estes problema? si es que no entonces has solucionado mi problema. Lo probare y te comento. Gracias por la ayuda igual si puedes comentar si tienes ese problema seria una gran ahorro de tiempo :)

Comment: @CarlosMoreno de nada trato de ayudar en lo que pueda, sobre tu problema, al momento de subir las imágenes lo estás visualizando de una vez con javascript? o lo estas visualizando en otra ruta?. SI puedes trate de mirar si hay errores en la consola del servidor y del navegador.

Comment: Para subir los ficheros puedes usar https://github.com/devconcept/multer-gridfs-storage

Answer (score 0):

es probable que ya sepas el motivo, pero para los que lleguen buscando la respuesta:

heroku no permite almacenar archivos que no sea de la app que estas desplegando en su servicio. luego de un rato lo borraran automaticamente, una alternativa es usar cloudinary que tienen una api, subes el archivo con tu app de node, y lo envias

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Se agradece el aporte tardío, pero podrías ser mas especifico con tu respuesta, incluir código y todo lo que haga falta? mira [answer] y de paso [tour]